# Export Word header Bookmark to Excel UserForm1 Textbox

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need VBA Code to get header bookmark in the Excel UserForm1 Textbox.  Please assist me.  I have got the page count, but not able to get this.  I have placed the Code below, which I've tried, but it is not working.

I get error at:

```
Set wbk = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Test-2.xlsm")
```

and

```
wst.txtstatementof.Text = "MyBookmark"
```

Thanks in advance.

Sub ExportBookmarksToExcel()
    Dim bk As Bookmark
    Dim appXl As Excel.Application
    Dim wbk As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wst As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim x As UserForm1

```
Set appXl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wbk = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Test-2.xlsm")
With appXl
    .Visible = True
    Set wbk = .Workbooks.Add
    Set wst = wbk.UserForm1
     wst.txtstatementof.Text = "MyBookmark"
  End With

'For each bk In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
    'lRow = lRow + 1
 '   wst.x.UserForm1.txtstatementof.Text = bk.Name
    'wst.Cells(lRow, 2) = bk.Range.Text
'Next bk
'wst.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you weren't far from success. Of course, this **must** fail:-

```
Set appXl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wbk = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Test-2.xlsm")
```

You can see that your Excel application is called `appXl`. Therefore it can't respond to `ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open`.

Below is the code that works.

```
Sub ExportBookmarksToExcel()

    ' MS Word variables:
    Dim Bk As Bookmark
    Dim R As Long

    ' MS Excel variables:
    Dim appXl As Excel.Application
    Dim Wbk As Excel.Workbook
    Dim Wst As Excel.Worksheet

    Set appXl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    With appXl
        .Visible = True
'        Set Wbk = .Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Test-2.xlsm")
        Set Wbk = .Workbooks.Add
        Set Wst = Wbk.Worksheets(1)
'        Wst.txtstatementof.Text = "MyBookmark"     ' what is "txtstatementof" ?
    End With

    R = 2                                           ' keep Row 1 for captions
    For Each Bk In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        Wst.Cells(R, 1) = Bk.Name
        Wst.Cells(R, 2) = Bk.Range.Text
        R = R + 1
    Next Bk
    Wst.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

 End Sub
```

Comment: Actually what I am trying to do is get Word Bookmark into Excel UserForm textbox.

Comment: Actually What I am trying to do is get the Word Bookmark into Excel Userform Textbox with the above code.  "txtstatementof" is the Textbox name in Excel UserForm.  "MyBookmark" is the bookmark in the Word Header part.

Comment: A Userform is neither Excel nor Word. It is VBA. So, you first need to create the form, with a Textbox in it. Then you can write code to open and close it and put text from a bookmark into its text box. It would seem that you don't need Excel in that case.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  I will explain it in detail.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Variatus.  The above code what I have mentioned is VBA only.  Word Header Bookmark is already created, it is an Enclosing Bookmark.  Textbox in Excel UserForm is also created.  I am new to VBA, Where I am not able to fix the problem in the code is to export Word Header Bookmark to Excel UserForm Textbox.  When I click a (Icon) on Quick Access Toolbar in Word the Bookmark should get exported to Excel UserForm Textbox.

Comment: I will explain you now what I am doing.

Comment: We work for an Insurance Claim Process; when two cars meet with an accident, insurance company takes driver's recorded statement.  We need to process those audios into Word Document  I need some data exported to Excel Userform from Word; i.e., number of pages in Word, Header Bookmark, and  (L) and (A) that occurs frequently in the document.  I have some existing data in Excel UserForm and Word details should get in Excel UserForm as well. Once those are added to Excel UserForm then the UserForm data goes to Sheet. Thanks in advance.  Please help me.  95% done, 5% left which is above, imp.

Comment: Focus on the term "Excel Userform". There is no such thing, as I have explained. Somebody coined the phrase. You seemed to treat it like a worksheet (perhaps by the name of "Userform"). But then you also used totally absurd (perhaps non-VBA) code in your attempts to address it. The word "txtstatementof" seems to have some relationship with this ominous "Userform". Perhaps this form is something neither Excel nor VBA. If we can find out what it is I might be able to help you - or I might be out of my depth, too.

Comment: I need help here, ( Wst.txtstatementof.Text = "MyBookmark"     ' what is "txtstatementof")